# Workflow process - Log the actions in JIRA

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I have created a workflow for content editors. Once they edit the contents, I would like that to be logged in JIRA. Is there a way to link the sitecore item with the JIRA ticket?

Comment: This is a duplicate of another question you asked 2 hours ago. Please do not open duplicate questions.

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain - This is focussed on one question. As you're aware, other question is on hold Also logging the actions is different from integrating sitecore and JIRA via the plugin